# Prevent evaluation of parameter inside function

Tags: functions, evaluation, polynomials, hold

I am learning mathematica, and I am stuck at the point where I want to pass an unevaluated expression (a polynomial) to a function and work with that expression / polynomial inside the function. For simplification reason, assume the following setup, which should give me the coefficients of the polynomial:

```
SetAttributes[myCoef, HoldAll]
myCoef[exp_] := CoefficientList[exp, Variables[exp]]
```

This works fine for the following call:

```
p = myCoef[5*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 3]
(* Returns {3, 0, 4, 5} *)
```

The problem is, when I set `x` on the global scope:

```
x = 5
p = myCoef[5*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 3]
(* Returns 728 *)
```

How can I prevent the evaluation of `5*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 3` to `728`?
What would I have to change in `myCoef` to make it work, even if `x` is defined globally?

Comment: You could use `\[FormalX]` (and similar) or maybe use pure functions as in `myCoef[5*#^3 + 4*#^2 + 3]`.

Comment: `SetAttributes[newPoly, HoldAll]` should probably have `myCoef` rather than `newPoly`?

Comment: Oh yes, that was just a typo when I wrote the example, for sure it is `myCoef`, I edit it.

Comment: Try: `myCoef[exp_]:=CoefficientList[HoldForm@exp,Variables[HoldForm@exp]]`. No need for the attribute even.

Comment: @N.J.Evans That returns 728 for me?

Comment: @N.J.Evans Also, `Varables@HoldForm[5*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 3]` returns `HoldForm[5*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 3]`.  This was the first thing I tried too.

Comment: Weird. For me it returns `{0,1}` which I just glossed over as being the right answer, but obviously it's a) wrong, b) in the correct form for an answer from `CoefficientList`. Obviously my suggestion wasn't correct, but I'm curious why it's giving two different answers. What version are you using?

Comment: @N.J.Evans I'm using `11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)`.  You?

Comment: @N.J.Evans Small mistake/sloppiness on my part:  your method returns `{728}` for me.  But you say you don't need a hold attribute -- how could that possibly work?  `myCoef[5*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 3]` would partially evaluate to `myCoef[728]` without the hold attribute, independent of any downvalues defined for `myCoef`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans OK, I'm now getting the same output as you -- `{0,1}`.  Somehow I'd replaced `HoldForm` with something that looked the same but contained non-printing characters -- its FullForm was `HoldFor\:200c\:200bm`.  Weird, but explains why what looked like `HoldForm` showed up in blue rather than black.

Comment: @N.J.Evans And this makes sense.  The output `{0,1}` is the same as `CoefficientList[ HoldForm@728, Variables[HoldForm@728] ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the simplest solution is to make sure you haven't defined the variables you're using in your polynomials, but there are other ways to go.

You could wrap the code in [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) or [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) :

```
Block[{x},
 myCoef[5*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 3]
 ]
```

> ```
> {3, 0, 4, 5}
> ```

If you wanted to, you could build this into `myCoef` by adding a second argument :

```
myCoef[exp_, varsToBlock_List] :=
 Block[varsToBlock,
  CoefficientList[exp, Variables[exp]]
  ]

x=2;
myCoef[5*x^3 + 4*x^2 + 3, {x}]
```

> ```
> {3, 0, 4, 5}
> ```

Note that the original form of `myCoef` still works for a variable that doesn't have a definition:

```
myCoef[5*y^3 + 4*y^2 + 3]
```

> ```
> {3, 0, 4, 5}
> ```

---

Of course, it would be nice to solve the problem without having to explicitly specify the variables which need to be held.  I'm unsure how to do this, but perhaps someone else will come up with a solution.

Comment: That's a nice solution! I will try this one when I come home, thanks! :)

Comment: I appreciate the accept, but I would strongly recommend waiting ~24 hours for others to submit solutions, particularly because I suspect a better solution is possible.